# Получить онтошения в запросе Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$hall = Hall::find($id)->load(['schedule_hall' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('day', 1);
}]);
```

Добрый день, код рабочий, как дальше получить отношения для **schedule_hall** ?

По аналогии с данным примером

```
$hall = Hall::find($id);
return $hall->load(['schedule_hall.programm.children.journal']);
```

Comment: Не ужели ни кто не знает ответа ?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто

```php
$hall = Hall::find($id)->load(['schedule_hall' => function ($query) {
    $query->with('programm.children.journal')->where('day', 1);
}]);
```

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли, код выше нужно изменить чтоб получить аналогию с кодом ниже

Comment: @Федотов, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно

Comment: Всего тебе хорошего)